# User permissions on a folder

Tags: permissions, folder

New to sharepoint and have a quick and simple question. I have a folder that I want to give someone full control of and also be able to add users to access it as they would like to. Will giving someone "Full Control" of a folder let them utilize the user permissions tool for this folder? If not, whats another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will, just show them where the permissions button is (or the ribbon command)